# Why External scheduler cannot be instantiated running spark on kubernetes with spark3.5.0?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

While trying to run spark application on kubernetes, i have created service account and clusterrolebinding to provide edit access

```
kubectl describe clusterrolebinding/spark-driver-rolebinding  -n spark-application 
Name:         spark-driver-rolebinding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  edit
Subjects:
  Kind            Name                          Namespace
  ----            ----                          ---------
  ServiceAccount  spark-driver-service-account  spark-application

kubectl describe serviceaccount/spark-driver-service-account  -n spark-application 
Name:                spark-driver-service-account
Namespace:           spark-application
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>
```

I am using spark base image with 3.5.0 version

Spark submit will happen, driver pod will go into error state immediately with below error.

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:3209)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:582)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2888)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1099)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093)
        at com.inmobi.cob.extreporting.ExternalReportingController$.main(ExternalReportingController.scala:25)
        at com.inmobi.cob.extreporting.ExternalReportingController.main(ExternalReportingController.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.makeExecutorPodsAllocator(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:3203)
        ... 19 more
```

Related issue: [Why External scheduler cannot be instantiated running spark on minikube/kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543646/why-external-scheduler-cannot-be-instantiated-running-spark-on-minikube-kubernet)

Above issue majorly points at missing edit access, which is being taken care in my case.
Please help in resolving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620929/3238085  : This suggests it could be Java version mismatch. Are you using the supported java versions ? For spark 3.5.0, supported Java versions are 8/11/17

Comment: We are using java 8 only